# sql query to find available dates

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I don't know this has a solution or I don't know which search term to use. This is my question. I have `4 Tables`. Which are

- `Available` - The dates of availability.
- `School_menu` - Which menu belongs to which school.
- `Menu` - Menus which consist of Items.
- `Item` - Usual Ordering Items.

I have been using below query to generate available dates. So someone can order for single date. Ex : 2015-12-17

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        *
FROM    Available AS a
        JOIN School_menu AS sm ON a.school_menu_id = sm.school_menu_id
        JOIN Menu AS m ON m.menu_id = sm.menu_id
        JOIN Item AS it ON m.menu_id = it.menu_id
WHERE   ( a.available_date BETWEEN '2015-12-27'
                           AND     '2016-02-05' )
        AND sm.sch_id = '7';
```

---

Recently, I have been told to add another feature. In detail,

Items,

- Pizza
- Submarine

if a user can order pizza on 12th of Dec. another press of a button should be able to order for the next few days in coming days. for 13th for 14th if Pizza is available for next few days queried through Available dates joined to menu. 1 itemis not a problem. what about 2 items. how do I write a query for that ? It didn't seem complicated on first. So, I've written a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        *
FROM    Available AS a
        JOIN School_menu AS sm ON a.school_menu_id = sm.school_menu_id
        JOIN Menu AS m ON m.menu_id = sm.menu_id
        JOIN Item AS it ON m.menu_id = it.menu_id
WHERE   ( a.available_date BETWEEN '2015-12-27'
                           AND     '2016-02-05' )
        AND sm.sch_id = '7'
        AND it.item_id IN ( 28, 31 )
        AND a.available_date != DATE(( '2016-01-05' ));
```

like this and messed up the whole ordering system.

How do I write the correct query !! Thanks

---

Added, SQL Fiddle
    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f44d/1

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get the scenario which you described with dates 12,13,14. Can you please elaborate little bit more ?

Comment: `Distinct *` ain't gonna do much for you. In the unlikely event that it does, then you have far bigger problems with your data

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Let's say you order pizza for the date 12th of december. It is already mentioned in Available date table as, Pizza is available on 12th (Item is linked to Menu, Menu is linked to School_menu and it is to Available date). If you press `Order for Next Month`. It should check if the menu of Pizza is available for the whole month using Available Date table. If it is available add to the order 13th of dec 14th of dec and so on for the entire month.

Comment: hi, can you provide a sql fiddle perhaps? one that already has sample data so we can concentrate on the query instead of how your tables look like. thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? It makes a difference to the options available to you? Can you remove the incorrect tag please. This will help others help you.

Comment: Can you try this one. 

SELECT DISTINCT 
        *
FROM    Available AS a
        JOIN School_menu AS sm ON a.school_menu_id = sm.school_menu_id and sm.sch_id = '7'
        JOIN Menu AS m ON m.menu_id = sm.menu_id
        JOIN Item AS it ON m.menu_id = it.menu_id and it.item_id IN ( 28, 31 )
WHERE   (a.available_date BETWEEN '2015-12-20' AND '2016-01-19' )
        AND a.available_date <> '2015-12-12';

Further, please update with scenario dates or email at naveed.ramzan@gmail.com

Comment: @t1t1an0 added SQLFiddle.

Comment: @destination-data sorry. The tag was suggested by SO. So, I added without concern. removed the tag

Comment: @NaveedRamzan what difference does it make. You clearly doesn't understand my question

Comment: @Strawberry I am not using `*` I just used that to test. Yes, but without distinct I've been getting some duplicate dates.

Comment: @RooshanAkthar : I am little bit confused with the dates. like the query I updated, can you please update with the dates. like in between case I think you need to put one month difference dates. and in available_date <> "" will be the today's or last order date ? Am I right ? Further, I have shifted where clause to relevant join area

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Question is not about between dates. It is about ITEMS. Basically, The 2 Items has to be available on the same date to be applied for the next order date. Which means, 

Thursday Menu is available for 17th. and it consists of Pizza, Submarine. 
So, when you click `Order for Next Month` It should check Thursday Menu is available for the days in the next month. and return those dates.

Comment: Hmmmm OK Now I think I am getting the idea. Can you send me db or relevant tables so I can try and then send you ? ? ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98316/discussion-between-rooshan-akthar-and-naveed-ramzan).

Comment: If you have to specify id values, you are probably doing something wrong. These values have no meaning to the users.

Comment: @jarlh This is not the user side. ids are generated by the script. I made like that for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this query by Grouping Available dates together and calculating the count of the groups and dynamically adjusting the having count.

---

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *, COUNT(*) 
   FROM Available AS a JOIN School_menu AS sm ON 
     a.school_menu_id = sm.school_menu_id JOIN Menu AS m ON 
     m.menu_id = sm.menu_id JOIN Item AS it ON m.menu_id = it.menu_id 
WHERE (a.available_date BETWEEN '2015-12-27' AND '2016-02-05') 
 AND sm.sch_id = '7' AND it.item_id IN (26, 25, 28) 
 AND a.available_date != DATE(('2016-01-04')) GROUP BY a.available_date
HAVING COUNT (a.available_date) > XX
xx = Dyamic Count
```